# How to remove a script from a existing migration file rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I pulled new changes from git, in this new changes there is a migration file,

```
def change
  add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
  User.all.each do |user|
   user.update(activated_at: user.updated_at)
 end    
end
```

now normally if I want to undo a migration i.e. remove a column say activated_at I have to run another migration to do so which is fine

but if I just want to remove the script i.e. `user.update(activated_at: user.updated_at)`, do I have to create another migration or do I just remove the script from the migration.

note: I don't want to remove the activated_at column, I just want to remove the script

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: what if another user or when you deploy you might find nil values with activated_at column.

Comment: @Nithin He set it first but now his requirement is changed or he got corrected with required logic so he want to know most elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove code and commit in master branch.

For systems on which this migration is run, you can run [rake task](http://For%20systems%20on%20which%20this%20migration%20is%20run) to run whatever you want to rollback (i.e. set `activated_on` to nil). Or you can run from rails console to set it nil.

And for new systems where you will clone and create database & run migration it will not get in touch with script as you removed code.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little more nuanced. In short you ask: can you change a migration that has already run? In general I would advice against it. In your case it also depends what has to happen with the `activated_at` field, I can imagine it would only be set once a user is "activated" (whatever that might mean in your application's context). So in that case: setting it to `updated_at` is wrong and would have to be "un-set"? Or set in a different way? So that would require a migration anyway. Or, also possible: the migration has not yet run on e.g. your production server and running the migration like this would be very hard to undo in a good way (well in this case it would be simple --set activated-at to nil again), then by all means adapt the migration, commit and upon deployment it will run a *better* migration. But ... you will have to manually restore/fix the situation on all machines the migration *did* run (your machine, your colleguaes, staging-testing platforms? ...)

So to help with your decision-process

- if you work in a team, and team-mates have checked out your code and run migrations, use a new migration to fix it
- if you have deployed to any server (testing/staging/production) that you would otherwise have to fix, add a new migration to fix it
- if you have not pushed your code to `master` (all code has remained local), adapt migrations at will :P

As an aside: I have seen developers who are so eager to only have "perfect" code in git, they will use all options git offers to clean up code: go back in history, squash commits, and I have to admit the result is very clear. That is very tempting and understandable, but imho we loose information (how did we get here and why?). Likewise it is tempting to have clean and minimal migrations, but personally I believe there is no shame that git and your migrations "show" the growing understanding of the problem area. I think it is one of the reasons it is called "developing": building software is a very iterative process and it is continually changing, and your code (git/history) and migrations are allowed to reflect that. My apologies if this last part is too meta and subjective.